# Resizing a window on maximization - Expression blend

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, expression-blend

In my project I have two menus, a datagrid and a statusbar. I have used a grid with four rows to position these items. However when I maximize the window, it resizes only horizontally, but I get some white space below the status bar. How can I avoid this?

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="310"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="70" />

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Menu Background="Gray" Grid.Row="0" >
    </Menu>
        <Menu Background="Black" Grid.Row="1" >
    </Menu>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" >
    </DataGrid>

    <StatusBar Grid.Row="3" Background="Green" Margin="0,0,0,29.296" >  
    </StatusBar>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Share your xaml, your layout will be your culprit but we'd have to see it to identify how.

Comment: @ChrisW. I have included the XAML code

Comment: So, you have a hard set height on every row. Which means you would expect it to only expand horizontally because you've explicitly told it not to reach beyond 310 pixels for that row's height. Change 310 to * with 310 just as the MinHeight and it will expand correctly.